# Not getting file's absolute path and file name while drowsing all types of file in my app using intent.setType("*/*")

Tags: android, file, android-intent

Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case FILE_REQUEST_CODE:
         selectedFromFileExplorer(data);
         break;
}
private void selectedFromFileExplorer(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
    }
}
```

Here i am getting this path while browsing

```
/document/image:56041
/document/video:55991
/storage/emulated/0/commerce/statistics/deviceId.txt
/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/56047/ORIGINAL/NONE/1070857477
```

How to get proper path of browsed file. I will create that same file with same file extension with different file name to my created folder.

How to achieve this. Thanks in Adv.

Comment: you dont need a path, instead you need `InputStream`, see `ContentResolver` API docs on how to get it

Comment: Using `InputStream` i can get the content  but I have to create or copy that file with same extension with different name . so i want the file name . How to get that.

Comment: query for a mime type, again see `ContentResolver` API docs